# SQL SERVER 2008: Populate the column names as values in a new column when the data in the data in the rest of the columns meets a certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am a newbie to SQL and just know enough to get the basic stuff done.I am sure my "problem" might sound real real idiotic, but any help is really appreciated.

I have a table with 4 columns, all the columns filled with data. All I need to do to add a new column and update it with the "column names" of the columns in which the data meets a specific condition.

For example,

The table that I have is of the below format

```
  1            2         3         4
150000         -       250000      -   
250000      200000       -         -   
 -          170000         -    200000   
150000      250000     300000  175000
```

The Output that I am expecting (considering the condition to the data in the columns > 100000)

```
 1          2        3         4         5 
 150,000    -       250,000    -        1,3 
 250,000  200,000    -         -        1,2 
 -        170,000    -       200,000    2,4 
 150,000  250,000   300,000  175,000    1,2,3,4
```

The column 5 needs to be inserted (which can be taken care of by using ALTER TABLE, ADD COLUMN), I am going on a merry go round trying to  populate the the column names (names of the columns 1,2,3,4 when the values in the column > 100000).

Btw, I need to perform this operation on 60 columns.

---

Hope the explanation of issue helps enlighting my ignorance

Comment: You will probably need a stored procedure to do it. I don't think it can be done with one sql stmt.

Comment: I was working on the SP itself, but was unable to figure out the logic to get the expected result!!

Comment: UPDATE temp_table SET FLAG = CASE WHEN C1>100000 THEN 'col1' WHEN C1>100000 AND C2>100000 THEN 'Col1,Col2' WHEN C2>100000 AND C1<100000 THEN 'Col2' -- this was the logic that I was thinking of, but implementing that for 60 columns would be a humongous task

Comment: Never wrote a stored proc in SQL server, but you basically want to have a loop and update the records inside the loop.

Comment: yes and no, wouldnt a loop check for a single column?? Yes, I do have a single condition to meet.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Reporting? Will you need to look into column 5 in the future and pull out the columns per row that match your "greater than x" criteria? What happens when you get a "and also greater than Y" requirement in the future?

Do you really need to store this data or do you just need to be able to run reports for rows where the column values meet some criteria?

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo : Yes, the main intention is for reporting. Fortunately, the condition X will only be the condition even in future and am pretty much sure that there would be no condition Y. I would need to store the data for furture purposes

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't "pre-fetch" that data into another column on the same table. SQL Server's fast enough to let you just run a reporting query to return this data on the fly. I also never believe any business person that says, "We'll only ever have 1 use for this data". :)

Comment: Thank you guys for all the inputs, I figured out a "merry go round" way of doing this.  To share, I created a SP to create the tables with a primary key, assuming col. A, which is present the table. In the same table, I have created multiple columns so that I could capture the NON NULL columns (hardcoded the column name in the query eg., Update Table, Set Col1='1' where 1 is not null) and used the same method to populate the rest of the col. names. Then used an INNER JOIN to update the col. 5 in the Main Table using the ID column as the PRIMARY KEY. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

```
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (ColName VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ColName VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Columns (ColName)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME col
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
STUFF(
(
    SELECT  'SELECT 
             CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM YourTable 
                                WHERE ' + ColName + ' > 100000) 
             THEN ''' + ColName + ''' 
             ELSE ''''
             END'
    FROM    @Columns
    FOR     XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

INSERT @Result
EXEC(@sql)

SELECT *
FROM @Result
WHERE ColName IS NOT NULL
```

The only part of this that doesn't work is the fact that `>` gets encoded by `FOR XML PATH`, which results in an error; you'll need to figure out a way to prevent that. If you replace the `>` with `=` (and select a value that exists) you will see it working.